# Socket provider no se reinicializa al hacer login

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy utilizando provider para manejar el estado de mi app, y tengo un provider o servicio que maneja un socket. Este socket se inicializa en el main de la app, pero algunos parámetros del socket se definen por algunas informaciones del usuario que hace login y se guardan en cache. Por lo que la data que viene por los eventos del socket es dinámica.

Ahora tengo el problema de que si hago login con mi usuario muestra la información correcta de mi usuario, al hacer logout y luego hacer login nuevamente con otros datos de otro usuario entonces no se reinicializa o no se refresca el estado de mi aplicación por lo que el socket no me trae los datos de dicho usuario. Es como que el socket ya se inicializo una vez y se quedo asi. Pero si hago un hot restart de la app en ese momento sí se inicializa y trae la info.

Cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de hacer login se vuelva a inicializar el provider de socket?

Este es un fragmente de mi socket provider

```
class SocketService with ChangeNotifier {
  ServerStatus _serverStatus = ServerStatus.Connecting;
  late IO.Socket _socket;
  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  ServerStatus get serverStatus => _serverStatus;
  IO.Socket get socket => _socket;

  SocketService() {
    _initConfig();
  }

  void _initConfig() {
    final String soketUrl = dotenv.env['SOCKET_URL'] ?? '';
    print(soketUrl);
    _socket = IO.io(soketUrl, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': true,
    });
```

y asi lo inicializo en el main.

```
class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => VehiclesService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GeocodingService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AlertsService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SocketService()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del constructor debajo de inicializar configuración implementa un notifyListerners

```
SocketService() {
    _initConfig(); 
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

o dentro del método cuando terminas de obtener los datos:

```
void _initConfig() {
    final String soketUrl = dotenv.env['SOCKET_URL'] ?? '';
    print(soketUrl);
    _socket = IO.io(soketUrl, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': true,
    });
    notifyListeners();
}
```